# How to append the loader component on particular div element in angular 8 .?

Tags: angular8

This is my ajax-loader.component.html

```
   `<div class="loadingplaceholder" *ngIf="isBusy">
        <label class="ajax-loader">
          <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
          <span class="loading-data-text">Loading</span>
        </label>
    </div>`
```

I need to add this loader component to the particular area where the data is loaded not on 
the whole section of document.

Comment: I need to append the loader and after that remove when the content is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your .loadingplaceholder `absolute` for that and the containing parent as `relative` for that.

```
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Now you can create a class for element in which you want to show your spinner;

```
.loading-container {
    position: relative
}
```

To use it you just have to add your `loading-container` class in element in which you want to show the spinner.

```
<div class="loading-container">
    --------- This is area where I want to show spinner ----------
    <div class="loadingplaceholder" *ngIf="isBusy">
        <label class="ajax-loader">
          <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
          <span class="loading-data-text">Loading</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So above solution will work fine, but I have some suggestion to follow good practices :

Instead of creating `loading-container` class or inline style I would suggest to use bootstrap class `position-relative`.

In angular we are supposed to create component for repetitive UI. In your case you would want to use this loader at many different places. So here you can create a component for that which accepts a boolean parameter to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for you comment . I have this component html I need to integrate in the particular
section where I need loading how to append this to particular div section . How to achieve that .?

Comment: @Hitesh Updated my Answer to make it better to understand